# iOS 13: UIScrollView no longer scrolls

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, ios13

I have a UIScrollView that contains a UISegmentedControl. The idea is that the user can scroll the segmented control back and forth to view options that fall outside the visible area of the device's screen. The user can also tap on a partially visible selection and it'll scroll to the center of the view. This all worked fine until iOS 13. Now the scroll view won't move via a touch although it does move programmatically, i.e., tapping a partially obscured option scrolls it to the middle of the screen.

[image]

The debugger output shows that the contentSize is set and is larger then the scroll view's frame:

```
<UIScrollView: 0x7f93ba0d2600; frame = (0 0; 375 30); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x600002f90360>; layer = <CALayer: 0x6000020fb880>; contentOffset: {188, 0}; contentSize: {1125, 30}; adjustedContentInset: {0, -187.5, 0, 187.5}>
```

I did subclass the scroll view and confirmed it's receiving touches by overriding touchesShouldBegin. Any idea of a change in iOS 13 that might cause this behavior?